# How can a Java RMI client connect to a Java RMI server using a domain name

Tags: java, rmi

I am writing an application using Java RMI. I have already created the client and server. However, I am using localhost only. I want to be able to use a domain name for the client to contact the server. I have already registered a domain name: hotel.ddns.net. I wish to be able to keep it inside a personal network, and nothing to do with port forwarding or so. The client and the server are found on different computers. I have been looking for solutions but these are not directly related to my question. Could you guys help me since I am still new to this?

Here is my client code:

```
package Hotel_;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java_rmi.java_rmi_interface;

public class ClientRMI {

    public java_rmi_interface connectToServer() throws NotBoundException{
    try{
        Registry myregistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099);
        java_rmi_interface myinterface = (java_rmi_interface)myregistry.lookup("bookingServer");
        System.out.println("client reaaaaaaady");
        
        
    return myinterface;
      
    }catch(RemoteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return null;
    }
}
```

here is my code for the server

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class ServerRMI {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        //Timer timer = new Timer();
        //timer.deletefunc();
        Registry myregitry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);//create a registry that can be 
        accessed on this port
        QueryCentre qs = new QueryCentre();//an instance of QueryCenter where remote methods are 
    found
        Naming.rebind("bookingServer", qs);//naming the server and passing the class where remote 
     methods are found
        System.out.println("server ready and waitiiiinnnggg!!!!!");
    }catch(RemoteException | MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you are working inside a local network and don't need to expose it to the Internet, then you must either use IP addresses or provide some means of name resolution (i.e. a DNS server) inside your network.  Dynamic DNS works on the Internet, not inside your NATted LAN with private addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working entirely within a personal network with private IP addresses (i.e. 192.168.x.x) then DDNS will do nothing for you.  It is intended to work with external, routable addresses only.

You have a few choices, from most complex to least complex they are:

1. Run a DNS server inside your LAN to map host names to local IP addresses.  This is a non-trivial undertaking, but might be interesting if you want to learn more about DNS.
2. Add lines in /etc/hosts to map names to the local IP addresses. You have to make sure every host that wants to talk to the server has the mapping in its copy of /etc/hosts.
3. Dispense with hostnames and just use IP addresses.

I strongly recommend #3 for your simple setup.

Comment: ...thx loaaadsss,i have been trying all sorts of codes and nothing was working...i will try the options that u said and let you know

Comment: ..in the 2nd option..when i will map names to local ip adress..if the ip address change,will the ip address in the file also change?

Comment: No  If you are on a personal LAN you can assign fixed IP address to devices based on their unique MAC address. You'll need to change the DHCP server configuration in your router to do that.

Comment: but what if i am using internet from mobile in terms of hotspot then how do i do that?

Comment: Then your original premise _"I wish to be able to keep it inside a personal network and nothing to do with port forwarding or so"_ was incorrect.  In that case to run the server inside the LAN you WILL have to set up port forwarding on your router, and dynamic DNS will be helpful if your ISP regularly changes your router's IP address.

Comment: so with dynamic dns..how do i do that?

Comment: That is really out of scope for StackOverflow. You might get some help a [su]